# Rails multi-tenant app, losing session when visiting another subdomain on some servers. How to debug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, devise, passenger

rails 3.17, devise 3.1.1 (recent upgrade from 2x, didn't affect anything), sessions stored in mongoid

Multi-tenant app, each account has its own subdomain. User can be a member of different accounts. When we open `account1.app.com`, we check if current user is a member of `account1` and then let him in. No sign in required. Session stays the same.

**Everything works fine with rspec/capybara feature tests. Also works with Pow** on my Mac. As a logged in user i can visit different accounts, session stays the same, a new cookie for each subdomain is created with the same `session_id`. I don't have to signin again when visiting other subdomains, session id stays the same.

This is the rspec test for that features. It passes, and this is how is supposed to work

```
scenario "User can switch between activated accounts he is a member of" do  
  account1 = Fabricate(:account, subdomain: 'account1', company_name: 'account1')
  account2 = Fabricate(:account, subdomain: 'account2', company_name: 'account2', owner: account1.owner)

  visit new_user_session_url subdomain: account1.subdomain
  fill_in 'user[email]', :with => account1.owner.email
  fill_in 'user[password]', :with => account1.owner.password
  click_button 'Sign in'

  # user inside his  account
  expect(current_url).to eq home_url(subdomain: account1.subdomain)

  #user inside his other account
  within "ul.account_menu" do
    click_link "account2"
  end
  expect(current_url).to eq home_url(subdomain: account2.subdomain)
end
```

**Doesn't work if i use webrick or thin**. When i (as logged in user from account1.app.com) try to visit another account like account2.app.com it loses my session.

- I'm getting redirected to sign in form
- session not loaded inside controller: `Rack::Session::Abstract::SessionHash:xxx not yet loaded`
- empty session with only `csrf_token` is created before signin form rendered.
- Also cookie with `session_id` for account2.app.com is not created. "This site has no cookies" says google chrome.
- If i try to sign in again - i get `WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` in log and redirected back to sign in form. 'csrf_token' in session equals `csrf-token` in header and `authenticity_token` in form of signin page.
- If i return to account1.app.com everything keeps working working there. My session is loaded and everything proceeds as intended.

**Partially works under Passenger Stand alone** in production.

- Again, i get redirected to sigin page once i try to visit another subdomain
- But this time cookie with NEW session id is created for that subdomain
- After signin form is submitted a NEW session is created and i'm finally inside.

Would greatly appreciate help, run out of ideas how to debug this.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to add `tld_length: 2` attribute to `config.session_store` at `initializers/session_store.rb`

Now it looks like that, and sessions started working across subdomains properly. I wish it was more obvious, spent quite some time researching it. Got misguided by inconsistent results from different webservers.

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :mongoid_store, domain: :all, tld_length: 2
```